# Compare two string arrays in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In a Postgres DB, I have 2 `varchar[]` columns in 2 tables with common ID that contain data as below:

[image: InputData]

I need to return rows where all values of `t_col` are present in `f_col` (with or without extra data).

Desired result:

[image: Output data]

I tried with the below as conditions in self join query.

```
select 
from t1 a, t2 b
where a.id=b.id
not (a.f_col @> b.t_col)
```

Comment: I tried to make a question of this, but still don't understand your objective. The given sample does not seem to reflect your description. Also: please provide sample data as **text**, never as image. And declare your version of Postgres (`SELECT version();`)

Comment: Your result seems to be the opposite of what you've asked.

Comment: missing AND before not, maybe?

Comment: You should state what result you are expecting and what your query is returning.